# how to implement in-memory mariadb to run junit tests in springboot, getting java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mariadb, spring-boot-test, mariadb4j

I'm trying to write JUnit integration test cases to my data services in my spring-boot application.

Initially, I used the H2 in-memory database provided by Spring. however, in my production environment, there are some tables eg: "user" which are preserved keywords in H2. So I want to implement in-memory embedded mariadb.

I came across the solution
https://objectpartners.com/2017/06/19/using-mariadb4j-for-a-spring-boot-embedded-database/

when i run my application with this solution, it get the below exception

```
2023-05-04 11:40:11.054  INFO 42276 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-04 11:40:14.235 ERROR 42276 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3307)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3307. Connection refused: connect
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:197) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1394) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.vorburger.mariaDB4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariaDB4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

test application.properties:

```
#Location of db files. delete this directory if you need to recreate from scratch
mariaDB4j.dataDir=/data/local

#Default is 3306, so using 3307 just in case it is already running on this machine
mariaDB4j.port=3307
app.mariaDB4j.databaseName=app_alpha

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

and configuration class:

```
import ch.vorburger.exec.ManagedProcessException;
import ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DBConfigurationBuilder;
import ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.springframework.MariaDB4jSpringService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class EmbeddedMariaDbConfig {
@Bean
MariaDB4jSpringService mariaDB4jSpringService() {
    return new MariaDB4jSpringService();
}

@Bean
DataSource dataSource(MariaDB4jSpringService mariaDB4jSpringService,
                      @Value("${app.mariaDB4j.databaseName}") String databaseName,
                      @Value("${spring.datasource.username}") String datasourceUsername,
                      @Value("${spring.datasource.password}") String datasourcePassword,
                      @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}") String datasourceDriver) throws ManagedProcessException {
    //Create our database with default root user and no password
    mariaDB4jSpringService.getDB().createDB(databaseName);

    DBConfigurationBuilder config = mariaDB4jSpringService.getConfiguration();

   return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .username(datasourceUsername)
            .password(datasourcePassword)
            .url(config.getURL(databaseName))
            .driverClassName(datasourceDriver)
            .build();
    }
}
```

please help